# Телеграм бот сам выключается, выходит из строя linux сервер ubuntu. Telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, python-telegram-bot

Начнем с того что после запуска .service файла на облачном linux сервере, с установленной операционной системой ubuntu бот прекрасно работает, день, два, рекорд неделю работал. Но как то случается то что бот сам по себе выключается, перестает отвечать на сообщения и прочее. Лечится это перезагрузкой. Я должен запустить бота на своем пк, подождать пока он ответит на все накопившиеся сообщения и только тогда он запускается на сервере. Я так полагаю, что для того что бы он вновь перезапустился нужно выполнить подключение к апи телеграм с другого устройства.

Что я пробовал для решения этой задачи.
В начале, я подумал что поможет цикл while, который при ошибке выведет мне ошибку и заново перезапустит бота, но это вызывало ошибку с кодом python 'source':

```
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        while True:
            try:
                bot.polling(none_stop=True)
            except Exception as e:
                file_name = 'error_log.txt'
                with open(file_name, 'a') as file:
                    file.write(f'{str(e)}\n')
                    file.write(traceback.format_exc())
                time.sleep(30)
                print(e)
```

далее я прибегнул к ограничению запросов к апи телеграм,

```
    def limit_calls(func):
        def wrapper(message):
            chat_id = message.chat.id
            current_time = time.time()

            if chat_id not in call_count:
                call_count[chat_id] = 0

            if chat_id not in last_call_time or current_time - last_call_time[chat_id] >= 1:
            call_count[chat_id] = 0
            last_call_time[chat_id] = current_time

            if call_count[chat_id] >= 5:
                time.sleep(1)
                func(message)
            else:
                call_count[chat_id] += 1
                func(message)
        return wrapper
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
    @limit_calls
    def commands(message):
        pass
```

Но тут опять получил ошибку. Я облазил весь интернет, обратился к друзьям, к чат gpt . Но ничего не нашел.Что делать? Как заставить бота работать бесперебойно? Можете дать решение данной проблемы или советы для того что бы я переписал код.

Примечание
код очень большой на 400 строк, сюда прикреплять не вижу смысла, выделил только основные части, они ниже

Весть код.

```
import telebot
import time
from telebot import apihelper

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

call_count = {}
last_call_time = {}

def limit_calls(func):
    def wrapper(message):
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        current_time = time.time()

        if chat_id not in call_count:
            call_count[chat_id] = 0

        if chat_id not in last_call_time or current_time - last_call_time[chat_id] >= 1:
            call_count[chat_id] = 0
            last_call_time[chat_id] = current_time

        if call_count[chat_id] >= 5:
            time.sleep(1)
            func(message)
        else:
            call_count[chat_id] += 1
            func(message)
    return wrapper


@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
@limit_calls
def commands(message):
    pass                                             
    **#Тут содержится вызов всех функций, но я посчитал не нужным их вставлять сюда.**


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        try:
            bot.polling(none_stop=True)
        except Exception as e:
            file_name = 'error_log.txt'
            with open(file_name, 'a') as file:
                file.write(f'{str(e)}\n')
                file.write(traceback.format_exc())
            time.sleep(30)
            print(e)
```

Текст ошибок прикреплю ниже.

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=25)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 416, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1348, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 316, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 277, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1270, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1128, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:




Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 719, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 400, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/six.py", line 703, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 665, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 423, in _make_request
    self._raise_timeout(err=e, url=url, timeout_value=read_timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 330, in _raise_timeout
    raise ReadTimeoutError(
urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=25)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:




Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 381, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 1104, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(non_stop=non_stop, interval=interval, timeout=timeout, long_polling_timeout=long_polling_timeout,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 1179, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 1140, in __threaded_polling
    polling_thread.raise_exceptions()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/telebot/util.py", line 110, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/telebot/util.py", line 92, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 661, in __retrieve_updates
    updates = self.get_updates(offset=(self.last_update_id + 1),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 633, in get_updates
    json_updates = apihelper.get_updates(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/telebot/apihelper.py", line 321, in get_updates
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/telebot/apihelper.py", line 158, in _make_request
    result = _get_req_session().request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 529, in send
    raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=25)
'source'



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 381, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 1104, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(non_stop=non_stop, interval=interval, timeout=timeout, long_polling_timeout=long_polling_timeout,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 1179, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 1140, in __threaded_polling
    polling_thread.raise_exceptions()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/telebot/util.py", line 110, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/telebot/util.py", line 92, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 661, in __retrieve_updates
    updates = self.get_updates(offset=(self.last_update_id + 1),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 636, in get_updates
    return [types.Update.de_json(ju) for ju in json_updates]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 636, in <listcomp>
    return [types.Update.de_json(ju) for ju in json_updates]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/telebot/types.py", line 207, in de_json
    chat_boost = ChatBoost.de_json(obj.get('chat_boost'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/telebot/types.py", line 9152, in de_json
    obj['source'] = ChatBoostSource.de_json(obj['source'])
KeyError: 'source'
'source'
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)